# Error while starting apache2 server in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, apache2, bugzilla

systemctl start apache2.service

Getting this error:-

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Logs of systemctl status apache2.service

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-06-02 08:24:55 IST; 49s ago
  Process: 9759 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)

Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 apachectl[9759]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 apachectl[9759]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 apachectl[9759]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 02 08:24:55 GS-4996 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: snippet does not contain the whole output. Share whole output as well as share `httpd -t ` command output.

Comment: @Pandurang i am using ubuntu, here it is apache2 only. Can you tell me how to execute httpd -t in ubuntu.

Comment: Please share below two command output: `ll /usr/sbin/apache2 ` `ll /etc/init.d/apache2`

Comment: For first command: ll /usr/sbin/apache2
Output is:
ls: cannot access '/usr/sbin/apache2': No such file or directory
For second command: ll /etc/init.d/apache2
Output is:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8181 Jul 16  2019 /etc/init.d/apache2*

Comment: start Apache using  `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the apache2 file is not available on server.
/usr/sbin/apache2 is provided by apache2-bin. apache2-bin is a dependency of the apache2 package, so apache2 will not work properly without it. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin   
sudo service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please attach error logs or the output of  "systemctl status apache2.service"

Answer (score 0):

My Best Solution No Need Restart .. After Long Time of se :)

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Stop nginx & Start apache**

That's it.

```
service nginx stop
systemctl restart postgresql
systemctl restart apache2
systemctl status apache2.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying for one day or something to install wordpress on my lubuntu. I tried several versions of installation, it is almost so hard as installing flutter :)  This works, this works not... And now, I am trying to install wordpress with XAMPP. And in /opt/lampp folder, where my XAMPP installation is, among other, i see **apache2** folder.

1. So, maybe, you should just uninstall XAMPP first, then install
   apache2
2. After installing apache2 try to restart your machine, then
   **sudo systemctl enable apache2**
   **sudo systemctl status apache2**  to see if it works
3. when trying to install php to lubuntu, system, among other, offers
   installation of apache2- so try this one:
   **sudo apt install php**